# Qlikview SQL: Retrieving Xml columns as data

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, qlikview

I have a database with the table 'Reports' in SQL Server. In that table is a column named 'Snippet'. this column is of type XML.
I now want to use the data in that XML column. The code i tried so far is:

```
SQL SELECT
T.ref.value ('Name[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Name,
T.ref.value ('Temperature[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Temperature
FROM rLoyalty.[dbo].[Reports] CROSS APPLY xml.nodes ('/HARDWARE_INFO/CPU_INFO/CORE') as T(ref);
```

My xml file looks like this:

```
<HARDWARE_INFO>
  <CPU_INFO>
    <CORE>
      <NAME>CPU Core #1</NAME>
      <TEMPERATURE>59</TEMPERATURE>
    </CORE>
    <CORE>
      <NAME>CPU Core #2</NAME>
      <TEMPERATURE>58</TEMPERATURE>
    </CORE>
    <CORE>
      <NAME>CPU Package</NAME>
      <TEMPERATURE>59</TEMPERATURE>
    </CORE>
  </CPU_INFO>
</HARDWARE_INFO>
```

But this gives me the error: ErrorSource: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server, ErrorMsg: The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml.

Comment: At a guess try `Snippet.nodes` instead of `xml.nodes`

Comment: Thank you very much @Nick.McDermaid that worked. now how do i flag your answer as correct haha?

Comment: this is not really a qlikview question, everything between "SQL Select" and ";" is sql-server related only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Snippet.nodes` instead of `xml.nodes`

`Snippet` is the column name that is of datatype `xml`

You use the `nodes` method on this XML column.

`xml.nodes` doesn't mean anything because (as far as I know) you don't have a column called `xml`

This would be the final code

```
SELECT
T.ref.value ('Name[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Name,
T.ref.value ('Temperature[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Temperature
FROM rLoyalty.[dbo].[Reports] 
CROSS APPLY 
Snippet.nodes ('/HARDWARE_INFO/CPU_INFO/CORE') as T(ref);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This fixes the problem but doesn't explain it. What is xml.nodes? What's snippet.nodes? Why does it matter which you choose?

Comment: What is XML nodes? that's a good question. That is what the OP had in his example code. What is Snippet nodes? He mentioned he had a column called `Snippet` which was of datatype `XML`, but Snippet did not appear in his sample code anywhere.